# Confused on multi-threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I tried to parallelize merge-sort using Java.Before multi-threading,every ran fine.But after creating two threads and running them independently,not only is lesser time not achieved but also the program runs infinitely and freezes the computer.Any reasons?Here's my program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Merge {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
System.out.println("Enter the length of the array");
Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
int arraySize=in.nextInt();
    int[] inputArray = new int[arraySize];

    Random rand=new Random();

    for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++)
    {
        inputArray[i]=rand.nextInt(100);
    }
    float start=System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Start time= "+start);

    mergeSort(inputArray);

    float end=System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println("Ending time= "+end);

    for(int i:inputArray)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Time take= "+(end-start));

 }

static void mergeSort(int[] A) {
    if (A.length > 1) {
        int q = A.length/2;

        int[] leftArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, q);
        int[] rightArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(A,q,A.length);
        Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable(){


            public void run() {

                mergeSort(leftArray);
            }

        });
        Thread t2=new Thread(new Runnable(){


            public void run() {
                mergeSort(rightArray);

            }

        });
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        merge(A,leftArray,rightArray);
    }
}

static void merge(int[] a, int[] l, int[] r) {
    int totElem = l.length + r.length;
    //int[] a = new int[totElem];
    int i,li,ri;
    i = li = ri = 0;
    while ( i < totElem) {
        if ((li < l.length) && (ri<r.length)) {
            if (l[li] < r[ri]) {
                a[i] = l[li];
                i++;
                li++;
            }
            else {
                a[i] = r[ri];
                i++;
                ri++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (li >= l.length) {
                while (ri < r.length) {
                    a[i] = r[ri];
                    i++;
                    ri++;
                }
            }
            if (ri >= r.length) {
                while (li < l.length) {
                    a[i] = l[li];
                    li++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //return a;

}

}
```

Comment: What array size did you input? Computer freezes most probably because you have too many active threads that the processor needs to handle, hence making other process unresponsive. However I cannot see why. Try printing `Thread.activeCount()` at the beginning of the `mergeSort`.

Comment: Well,I think that is the case.Array size was around 3500000.Actually,I am testing normal merge-sort to parallel merge-sort at different values of n.For less than 1000000,it is too fast and the time it takes is always 0.0.

Comment: Firstly, don't copy a range of the array; you should be able to merge sort with indices alone. Also, is this what you really want to do? Eventually, you will be making a thread to handle a single element array. That's a lot of overhead to find out you're done. Are you sure you shouldn't be breaking the sort into threads that perform non-threaded merge sorts on *segments* of the array?

Comment: @PrashantPandey 3.5M active threads is quite a lot, given that your CPU can only execute as many at a time as the number of cores it has (I guess 4 or 8).

Comment: I have used only two threads.3.5M is the number of elements in the array,isn't it?Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No, you recursively call `mergesort` which starts up two threads each time.

Comment: At the first level, you will have 2 threads, they will cease execution at `join` and at the second level you will have 4 active threads. Then these 6 are waiting at `join` and on the next level of recursion you have 8 active threads. In the end you will have as many active threads as the length of the array + another that many waiting threads.

Comment: Oh man,I totally did not take that into notice.Thank God my CPU did not blow up.Thanks dude.Any idea on how we could parallelize it?

Comment: Take the threading code out of `mergesort` and instead start up two threads which call `mergesort` each having half the array. Then you have two threads each sorting half the array in parallel.

Comment: You could use thread pool and instead of creating new threads taking them from the pool. Set its size to the number of cores on your CPU (possibly minus one if you want your computer to be usable when the program is running). The difficult part will be replacing `join`, because you will need to somehow mark at the end of thread task what part of array has been already processed. Why are you trying to parallelize it at all?

Comment: Just for fun,you know.And it is that the CPU can run only that number of threads as the no. of cores it has?Can't one core handle many threads using hyper-threading?Forgive me if it is  too basic a question.I am a beginner in multi-threading.

Comment: Although hyper threading allows multiple threads to be executed simultaneously by single physical core, it does not increase the number of instructions the core can execute per second. I think that the only actual gain in this case is from rarer context switching. A lot also depends on how busy the threads are. Any I/O or threads with synchronisation will have some "wait times" and hence will not use up entire core, but a loop with array operations like here will bump the core's usage up to 100%.